# How to compare data in range number without using explode

Tags: php, laravel

I've table target

```
id | target_percent
1  | 1-50
2  | 50-100
3  | 150-200
```

Can I use data target_percent to compare number example :

```
$a = 55;
```

I want to find what target id where $a in .

now I loop data and use explode to do something like this .

```
       foreach ($target as $item) {
            $percent = explode("-", $item->target_percent);
            $startpercent = (int)$percent[0];
            $endpercent = (int)$percent[1];
            if ($startpercent <= $percentSell && $percentSell <= $endpercent) {
               return $item->id
            } 
        }
```

this way everything work but It too complicated.

I just want to know is their some way to make it easier?

Comment: Wouldn't a regex match work with this ? Like `preg_match("/[$target_percent]/", $a);` ?

Answer (score 0):

It possible to change table columns to `id, target_percent_from, target_percent_to`?

If it is, You can use Laravel DB and write something like this:

```
\DB::table('target')
    ->where('target_percent_from', '>', $a)
    ->where('target_percent_to',   '<', $a)
    ->get();
```